# how to add bitmap image to buttons in MFC?

Tags: mfc, cbitmap

I am Trying to add an image to an existing button..I have done that to an extent, the problem is I can add an ownerdrawn Image but am not able to add the extact image that I want.. for the example see the below code

```
CButton* pBtn= (CButton*)GetDlgItem(ID_WIZBACK);

   pBtn->ModifyStyle( 0, BS_ICON );

   HICON hIcn= (HICON)LoadImage(
        AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON3),
        IMAGE_ICON,
        0,0, // use actual size
        LR_DEFAULTCOLOR
    );

    pBtn->SetIcon( hIcn );
```

with the above code am converting the bitmap to an icon to add to my button...how can I add the exact Bitmap image directly to an existing button.Please help me frnds..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually fixed the problem..what I did is I replaced the HICON with HBITMAP and its working perfect...basically both would work fine but in my case when I loaded the icon into the button the background of the icon was not changing...I tried Bitmap then it work great. Now am working on positioning the Image and to add text...think I could go through

Answer (score 5):

**Steps for assigning bitmap to button in mfc :**

1. Create object of bitmap
2. Load bitmap by using **LoadBitmap()**
3. Get Handle of button using **id** and **GetDlgItem()** method
4. Modify style so that we can assign bitmap to it
5. use **SetBitmap()** on button's handle to assign bitmap

Code :

```
CBitmap bmp;

bmp.LoadBitmap( IDB_BITMAP4 );

CButton* pButton = (CButton* )GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1);

pButton->ModifyStyle(0,BS_BITMAP);

pButton->SetBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't know how much this helped out.  Thanks for posting.  Also have to change a few other things to bitmap as well ...

```
CButton* pBtn= (CButton*)GetDlgItem(ID_MYDIALOG);
pBtn->ModifyStyle( 0, BS_BITMAP );

HBITMAP hIcn= (HBITMAP)LoadImage(
  AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance,
  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MYPIC),
  IMAGE_BITMAP,
  0,0, // use actual size
  LR_DEFAULTCOLOR
  );

pBtn->SetBitmap( hIcn );
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass existing button using `CBitmapButton::SubclassWindow`, then use `LoadBitmaps`.

Comment: How to call SubclassWindow?

Answer (score 0):

Use the button classes from the Feature Pack. They have support for showing both text and images on buttons, your regular button can't do that. Look at the 'samples' directory in your VS installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some ideas to @Amruta Ghodke 's answer:

You can resize your button using the `GetWindowRect` and `SetWindowPos` functions. See an example below:

```
CRect rc;

pButton->GetWindowRect(rc);
pButton->SetWindowPos(NULL, rc.left, rc.top, myWidth, myHeight, SWP_NOSENDCHANGING | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
```

If you want to display transparent images, use the software [Pixelformer](http://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/download.html) to convert your PNGs to Alpha-enabled BMPs. You will have to:

1. Go to Image->Properties and set `RGB color with alpha channel`
2. Export the file using format `A8:R8:G8:B8` and disabled `Premultiplied alpha` and `Top-down row order`